# TypeScript Sort Object by Object in Array

Tags: arrays, typescript

Does anyone know how sort Array with Person by value TaskTime in tasks?

```
export class Person {
    Id: string;
    Email: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Presence: boolean;
    RegisterTime: Date;
    tasks: Array<Task>
}

export class Task {
    TaskName: string;
    DoneTask: boolean;
    TaskTime: number;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

The javascript `Array` object comes with a builtin [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you pass it a compare function like this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
        return 1;
    }

    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
}
```

So in your case:

```
let person = new Person();
console.log(person.tasks.sort((task1, task2) => task1.TaskTime - task2.TaskTime));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to follow such way to sort your array. The sample code below will sort the array in descending order by blockId field.

```
this.itemList.sort((left, right): number => {
  if (left.blockId < right.blockId) return 1;
  if (left.blockId > right.blockId) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```