# how to sort object array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I am new in TypeScript. I might be asking a rookie question. I have the following array of objects. I would like to sort it either by age or name. This question was asked before. I tried following after reading [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)  [And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348556/typescript-sort-object-by-object-in-array). I couldn't compile it in TypeScript.

```
    sortData2() {
  const testData: object[] =  [
    {
      name: 'name 1',
      age: 20,
      sex: 'M',
      height: 7.5
    },
    {
      name: 'name 1',
      age: 10,
      sex: 'M',
      height: 6.5
    },
    {
      name: 'name 3',
      age: 30,
      sex: 'F',
      height: 4.5
    }
  ];

  testData.sort( (a, b) => {
      return compare(a, b);
  });

  
  function compare(a: number | string | object, b: number | string | object) {
    // compiler error Property 'age' does not exist on type 'string | number | object'.
    return (a.age < b.age ? -1 : 1);
  }
  console.log(testData);
}
```

How can I sort it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring compare as a function instead of defining it inline ? You should also probably remove the `object[]` type: typescript will infer something better

Comment: `a` and `b` wouldn't be `number | string | object` only `object`. And even then, you are better off defining an interface for your objects, so you can more accurately typecheck.

Comment: Actually, I got an array of objects from another function call. I can’t change that 3rd party api call. So I can’t define any kind of interface of my own.

Comment: You cannot write `interface Person {name: string, age: number, sex: 'F' | 'M, height: number }`?

Comment: I tried to simulate my real code and issue by this simple person like interface.  My real code is far more complex than this simple interface.

Comment: You're still able to define an interface for the data. It doesn't even need to be comprehensive - if you only use three properties, you can specify those.

Comment: You can "cast" (type assert) the object array to predefined type: `(testData as Person[]).sort(compare);` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN7JwDmEAXMiAK4C2ARtMgL4DcAUKwjhmMpNwCJwwcclloArCAjABtALrIAvMhmtk+NeopxqZZAHIQOlAEZ9AGk3riegEwAGS1uQYIAD3L6AshavIAFhDARP5g5ADsAHQArJqMThrORrqeyaa+zjbkJo5+rh4GPgnqgcGh5ABsMXEJeH5pqcbIAMwZWlktuc75ngBibSVBIWHIACzV6oyscmysABR8YILChBhomDjyAJSR2FBgc5zUAA5wUBBbszCUINLAOMhHp+dzIutQ2CDmyLTk6B84LaJZDnMCUKC4V6RGzIAA8P2hJGQAH5kABaEzIbKXViMIA

Comment: Yes, that is working fine. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your compare function, you are saying that a and b can be an object, string, or number; but then you are checking a.age, which doesn't make sense unless a and b are objects which have the property age.  So why are you accepting so many possible types here?

Replace this:

```
function compare(a: number | string | object, b: number | string | object) {
    return (a.age < b.age ? -1 : 1);
}
```

With this:

```
function compareAge(a: {age: number}, b: {age: number}): number {
    return (a.age < b.age ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Or better yet, this, which better handles the case where a.age and b.age are equal.  An [array.sort compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should return a number less than 0 if a is less than b, greater than 0 if a is greater than b, or 0 if they are equal.  The actually value of the number doesn't matter -- just the sign.  So you *can* map to -1 or 1, but it is unnecessary. A simple subtraction allows for returning positive, negative, and 0.

```
function compareAge(a: {age: number}, b: {age: number}): number {
    return a.age - b.age;
}
```

You will still get an error when calling `testData.sort( compareAge );` because you have declared a very vague type with `testData: object[]`.  You can either remove this typing entirely and Typescript will infer the proper type, or you can declare it as a more specific type, like `testData: Person[]`.  You will be able to sort with `compareAge` as long as the elements of testData (or any other array) extend `{age: number}`.